# Do We Always Need To Deallocate Memory When Deep Copying Using Copy Assignment Operator?

Tags: c++, deep-copy

This is probably a dumb question, but out of curiosity I'll ask this one anyway.

In most of the examples I saw, it is always stated that we need to deallocate and then reallocate memory in the definition of the copy assignment operator when deep copying is needed. But is this always the case? What if in the default constructor the pointer member variable is already allocated memory? Is it fine to just assign/overwrite the value the pointer is pointing to like this:

```
Foo& Foo::operator =(const Foo& obj)
{
   *(this->ptr) = *(obj.ptr);

   return *this;
}
```

Instead of this

```
Foo& Foo::operator =(const Foo& obj)
{
   delete this->ptr;
   this->ptr = new int;
   *(this->ptr) = *(obj.ptr);

   return *this;
}
```

If this is considered bad practice, can you please explain and show an example why is it so.

Comment: Not a dumb question at all.

Comment: The first (in this simplified example) is OK.The second has needless memory management.  (Are you hiding a class definition by using a member pointer?)

Comment: In fact, if your class contains, say, a `std::vector<int>`, and you assign, then the vectors are assigned precisely in the way you describe; they do *not* destroy their allocation and reallocate (if there's space). You can think of assignment as an optimisation of "destroy and reconstruct". Not all things are assignable, though, and the common code example only requires copyability, not assignability. And if you're dealing with a polymorphic hierarchy, replace "copy" with "clone", which can only be done dynamically.

Comment: @DieterLücking, no I'm not hiding any class definition.

Comment: @RyklonZen ...then, you might replace that pointer by a non-pointer member (`int value` here)

Comment: @KerrekSB, thanks for the tidbit of knowledge.

Comment: @DieterLücking, Oh, I get your point. For the simplicity of my example I just made the pointer int. It could be a class or any other type.

Comment: @RyklonZen That second example you posted has a flaw in that if `new` throws an exception, the `Foo` object is in an inconsistent state since `ptr` was already deleted.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, thanks. Indeed a potential exception regarding new is a problem. That is actually the example I am talking about.